# SQL Query -Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, publicationlist

```sql
select a.Email,
    case
    when l.ListName = 'Business other marketing communications'
    then
        case 
        when l.Status='Active'
        then '1'
        else '0'
        end
        as [Business_other_marketing_communications]
    else
    when l.ListName = 'Business content and insights'
    then
        case 
        when l.Status='Active'
        then '1'
        else '0'
        end
        as [Business_content_and_insights]
    else
    when l.ListName = 'Business products and services'
    then
        case 
        when l.Status='Active'
        then '1'
        else '0'
        end
        as [Business_products_and_services]
    end

FROM [Publication List Checker] a
inner join [_ListSubscribers] l on a.Email=l.EmailAddress
WHERE l.ListName = 'Business other marketing communications' or l.ListName = 'Business content and insights'
or  l.ListName ='Business products and services'
```

[image]

Comment: This gives me this error  "An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'."

Comment: Are you trying to always set a value for the 3 fields or are you trying to conditionally set a value based on the ListName that you get from a particular row? If you're trying to always set a value, yes it's possible. If you're trying to conditionally set a value I would split this into 3 queries as there will be other rows that will dictate that the field you want to conditionally use needs to exist. When it does that you'd be putting a NULL value in that field.

Comment: I need to set the values based on the list and the status.

Comment: What I mean is, if you consider the first row of data you process, if the value of ListName is "Business other marketing communications", do you want to set "Business_other_marketing_communications to be true/false AND Business_content_and_insights to be true/false AND Business_products_and_services to be true/false " or do you only want to set Business_other_marketing_communications to be true/false and for it to not try and set a value for the other fields?

Comment: I want to update only one field to true/false and not update others its related to this request, can you suggest me a better way to do?https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/331801/publication-list-sync

Comment: When you say that its possible to always set a value for the 3 fields can you let me know how to do that?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to give a complete description of the challenge you are currently facing, including any error text. See [ask] and [help/on-topic] for more about our format.

Comment: If you want to only update one field you will need 3 queries - keep in mind what you are doing here is creating a 2 dimensional array of data, so once a field is there you have to set something in it and it will then be overwriting the value that was previously in that field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a value for all 3 fields would look something like this (keep in mind I haven't tested this query). This will set each field to either be 1 or 0...if you want it to potentially be NULL as well if the ListName doesn't match at all let me know. Also keep in mind you're not setting true/false here that might work in a Boolean field - you are creating a string with the value 0 or 1

```
SELECT a.[Email],
CASE
  WHEN l.[ListName] = 'Business other marketing communications' AND l.[Status] = 'Active' THEN '1'
  ELSE '0'
END AS [Business_other_marketing_communications],
CASE
  WHEN l.[ListName] = 'Business content and insights' AND l.[Status] = 'Active' THEN '1'
  ELSE '0'
END AS [Business_content_and_insights],
CASE
  WHEN l.[ListName] = 'Business products and services' AND l.[Status] = 'Active' THEN '1'
  ELSE '0'
END AS [Business_products_and_services]
FROM [Publication List Checker] a
INNER JOIN [_ListSubscribers] l on a.[Email] = l.[EmailAddress]
WHERE l.[ListName] IN ('Business other marketing communications', 'Business content and insights', l.ListName ='Business products and services')
```

Comment: Thanks @Jarrett Bush, so this is creating one row for each active state if the subscriber is active in two lists two records are created of him. Added pic for your reference.

Comment: @nandhiniramchandran given what you're trying to do it makes the most sense to make this 3 individual queries. It's the only way you will end up with a single row for each record that only updates where it should. Your first query should be set to overwrite and the next two should be set to update - that way each time you run the automation you won't have legacy data for records that may be removed from each list.

Comment: So the first query would be
SELECT a.[Email],
CASE
  WHEN l.[ListName] = 'Business other marketing communications' AND l.[Status] = 'Active' THEN '1'
  ELSE '0'
END AS [Business_other_marketing_communications]
FROM [Publication List Checker] a
INNER JOIN [_ListSubscribers] l on a.[Email] = l.[EmailAddress]
WHERE l.[ListName] = 'Business other marketing communications'

Comment: Yes,got it @Jarrett Bush. Thanks for your inputs!